# Is it possible to get gVim to remember window size?

Tags: session, vim, window, persistence

I know how to [set the initial window size](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Maximize_or_set_initial_window_size) in gVim, but how do I get it to automatically restore the window dimensions from last session? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit: Corrected my answer. The mentioned winsize sessionoption only refers to the vim internal window layout, not the external dimensions.

---

If you use

```
:mksession
```

and load the session on vim startup with

```
gvim -S Session.vim
```

you can include the window position and size into the session by including winpos and resize in the sessionoptions, see

```
:help  'sessionoptions
```

With autocommands you could even automate the saving and restoring of the session on Vim entry and exit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm still quite new to Vim, so I'm not terribly experienced with autocommands. How would I get them to fire on entry and exit?

Comment: See :help autocommand, especially the GUIEnter, VIMEnter, VIMLeave events look promising.

Comment: Session saving also saves last opened files and tends to ignore these, when opening single files with Vim.

There's a script in Wikia, which does it in a cleaner manner (i.e. without messing around with other session elements): http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position

Answer (score 12):

These lines save and restore just the position and size:

```
set sessionoptions+=resize,winpos
autocmd VIMEnter * :source C:/session.vim
autocmd VIMLeave * :mksession! C:/session.vim
```

Comment: This a nice idea, but session saving also saves last opened files and tends to ignore these, when opening single files with Vim.

There's a script in Wikia, which does it in a cleaner manner (i.e. without messing around with other session elements): http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position

Answer (score 7):

Additionally:

In your `.vimrc`:

```
set ssop+=resize,winpos,winsize,blank,buffers,curdir,folds,help,options,tabpages
```

Then, use the script from [this article](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position). It works beautifully!

Comment: Could you describe what's the relation between the referenced script and the session options you suggest, please? Why they're needed? That script is managing everything itself (saves the window size and position in a custom file).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question, and to expand on the above answer, you can simply add the following to your `.vimrc` to get the behaviour you want:

```
set sessionoptions+=resize,winpos
```

see `:h ssop`

Comment: Aren't you missing anything? It didn't help in my case (Ubuntu 22.04, gVim 8.2). I have also added `winsize`, but it didn't have any impact.

Comment: Those session options control the behavior of the session management, but sessions are not being saved automatically, so it does nothing by itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
gvim -geom 85x55
```

as in, putting this in your .bashrc:

```
alias G='gvim -geom 85x55'
```

Comment: I'm afraid that it will work only when running gVim from the bash. You would have to add those command line arguments to many other places to make it a really universal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want vim to open to the same size every time, you can edit your user's vimrc in `C:/Users/<yourUserName>/_vimrc` (this is preferred to editing the system _vimrc in your vim installation folder)
to include the line `set lines=<yourHeight> columns=<yourWidth>`