# Restore size of splits in a vim session

Tags: vim

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594838/is-it-possible-to-get-gvim-to-remember-window-size) i found a link to [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Restore_screen_size_and_position) script which saves the screen size and position when exiting vim. If i use `:mksession ~/session.vim` in fullscreen mode with several splits, exit vim (gvim) and open it like: `gvim -S ~/session.vim` it messes up the sizes of the splits (pretty randomly. All splits have different sizes).  They are all shifted to the left. Is there already a way of doing this properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you verified your `'sessionoptions'`? It should include 'resize' and 'winsize' at the very least to get what you're looking for. `:help 'ssop'` will give you the list of options to set for what gets saved into session files.

Comment: i added resize and now this raises another weird behaviour: i open gvim, toggle to fullscreen and make 3 empty split windows with ^Wv. i use `mksession ~/session.vim` close gvim and reopen it from console with `gvim -S ~/session.vim` and it opens in almost fullscreen with only 2 blank splits. (i removed the script btw)

Comment: If I open buffers in the three splits (or open one buffer then do two splits) and then `:mks` and then use that session to start gVim, I get the three splits. If I just split the scratch buffer then I don't get any splits when restarting gVim with that session.

Comment: Allowing your desktop manager to resize gVim has always given me weird results along the bottom and right edges. I don't know if there's a way to force the window to be maximized via session options or otherwise; the session should be correctly restoring the number of characters wide and tall your window is nonetheless. Perhaps if you want gVim to start maximized you just need to tell the window manager to maximize it when you start it?

Comment: Maybe i forgot to mention that entering vim maximized works fine with the `sessionoptions`. Only the size of the splits is messed up. This can be fixed with a `^W=`. Still i would like to know how to do this with opening a session.